# Do bxSlider option "easing" works with option "auto: true"?

Tags: bxslider, easing

im using bxslider, i want to use easing option wit option auto: true
Does it works like that or only with controls?

My code:

```
<script>
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
   mode: 'horizontal',
  useCSS: false,
  infiniteLoop: false,
  hideControlOnEnd: true,
  easing: 'easeOutElastic',
  speed: 2000

});
</script>
```

It's dont work, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use http://v3.bxslider.com/

this version if you work with auto: true